# slds fixed header is not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Fixed Header slds is not working in LWC.

Sample Code used

```
<template> 
<div class="slds-box slds-theme--default"> 
    <div class="slds-table--header-fixed_container" style="height:150px;">
        <div class="slds-scrollable_y" style="height:100%;">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">
                            Account Name
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            Account Number
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            Industry
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            Rating
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            Type
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            Phone
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-label="Account Name">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Account Number">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Industry">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Rating">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Type">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Phone">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-label="Account Name">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Account Number">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Industry">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Rating">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Type">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Phone">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-label="Account Name">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Account Number">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Industry">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Rating">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Type">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Phone">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-label="Account Name">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Account Number">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Industry">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Rating">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Type">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Phone">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-label="Account Name">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Account Number">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Industry">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Rating">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Type">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Phone">
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Scrolling is working. But, header is not getting fixed. It is becoming part of scrolling.

[image]

Comment: I think you can check this link once: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183660/slds-table-with-fixed-header

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. That code is for Aura Component. I am using LWC.

Comment: will it be possible to share the code to test it in dev org

Comment: @Anutej - I have updated the original question with the full code to replicate the issue. Header is not fixed. Header is also part of the Scrolling.

Comment: Update: Using the below CSS, I was able to achieve the fixed header. But, I am more leaning towards Salesforce SLDS solution.

.tableFixHead {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 250px;
}

.tableFixHead table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

.tableFixHead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 4;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made Few alterations to the above code using the code present in this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183660/slds-table-with-fixed-header/189099#189099) and below code worked for me:

```
<template> 
<div class="slds-box slds-theme--default"> 

<div class="slds-table--header-fixed_container" style="height:150px;">
    
    <div class="slds-scrollable_y" style="height:100%;">
        
        <table class="slds-table--header-fixed slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped">
            
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-cell-fixed">Account Name</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-cell-fixed">Account Number</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-cell-fixed">Industry</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-cell-fixed">Rating</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-cell-fixed">Type</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-cell-fixed">Phone</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Account Name">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Account Number">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Industry">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Rating">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Type">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Phone">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Account Name">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Account Number">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Industry">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Rating">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Type">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Phone">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Account Name">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Account Number">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Industry">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Rating">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Type">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Phone">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Account Name">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Account Number">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Industry">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Rating">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Type">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Phone">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Account Name">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Account Number">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Industry">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Rating">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Type">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Phone">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">Test</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the edited answer, I made changes to the class values in the table tag [i.e., changed from class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table--header-fixed" to class="slds-table--header-fixed slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped"] and the div tag in the th tag [i.e., removed the slds-truncate]

Removed few duplicate rows to decrease the number of lines.

Comment: The table header is fixed. Thank you @anutej. I used your code. Still, the look and feel is not good. Phone field is completely hidden.

Comment: I have updated the class values and this has been fixed. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Anutej. It is working. I am still using custom CSS for more responsiveness.

Comment: Glad to know the changes made were helpful.