# Lightning Table Fixed Headers will not center

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, table

I am referencing below article in my code, applying fixed headers. When I do this I'm not able to center align the column headers or change the height of the header row. I have tried `class="text-align:center"`, `slds-align_absolute-center`, removed various other slds tags thinking they're interfering with each other. Added centering tags to the Style for the component. Nothing seems to work. I currently do not have anything in the style sheet for the lightning component.

[SLDS table with fixed header](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183660/slds-table-with-fixed-header)

```
<div class="slds-table--header-fixed_container" style="height:450px;">
    <div class="slds-scrollable_y" style="height:100%;">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_fixed-layout slds-table--header-fixed">
                <thead>
                <tr class="height:15px">
                    <th scope="col" width="6%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="Subsidiary">Subsidiary</div></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="10%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="Description">Description</div></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="9%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="TotalBudget">Total <br/> Budget</div></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="8%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="SpentToDate">Spent To <br/> Date</div></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="8%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="GoForwardCosts">Go Forward <br/> Costs</div></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="17%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="Notes">Notes</div></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="7%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="Month1">{!v.first}</div></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="7%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="Month2">{!v.second}</div></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="7%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="Month3">{!v.third}</div></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="7%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="Month4">{!v.fourth}</div></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="7%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="Month5">{!v.fifth}</div></th>
                    <th scope="col" width="7%"><div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed slds-align_absolute-center" title="Month6">{!v.sixth}</div></th>
                </tr> 
            </thead>  
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.BudgetRecords}" var="budget" indexVar="idx">
                    <c:MonthlyBudgetDetail aura:id="childComp" showSaveCancelBtn="{!v.showSaveCancelBtn}" 
                                           BudgetRec="{!budget}" index="{!idx}" 
                                           BudgetItemListUpdate="{!v.BudgetItemRecords}"
                                           column0="{!v.first}" column1="{!v.second}" column2="{!v.third}"
                                           column3="{!v.fourth}" column4="{!v.fifth}" column5="{!v.sixth}"
                                           first="{!v.date0}" second="{!v.date1}" third="{!v.date2}"
                                           fourth="{!v.date3}" fifth="{!v.date4}" sixth="{!v.date5}"
                                           />
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

[image]